# AIR for iOS- code to automatically relaunch an application once a week

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air

Struggling with maintenance on deployed kiosk installations created using AIR.
The problem is that we need to restart the applications once a week but from what I've researched even MDM solutions with iOS7 don't allow this.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this in code, i.e. restart an AIR for iOS application once a week(or even every night)?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible on iOS, regardless of technology used to create the app. Could you provide the reasoning for wanting this functionality? Perhaps there is another way.

Comment: If at all possible you'd have to look into jail breaking the devices and some custom software to do it. This definitely isn't easy to do within the normal SDK.